# How to pass the value of a variable between 2 different sites

Tags: php, laravel

So. There is 2 different sites.
site_1 and site_2

Site_1:

```
PHP 7.3
Laravel 6.0
MYSQL
Contains corporate portal with helpdesk,news and so.
```

Site_2:

```
PHP 7.2
Laravel 5.6
MYSQL
Contains Videoportal(yeah like youtube:)) with users and webcams from construction sites.
```

On site_1 i have a class User with some properties (i.e. user id,department,and so) contains in db. 
On site_2 i have different DB with user_id and cams .I want to select only webcams that belongs to user from site_1.

How can i pass value of User_id from site_1 to site_2 to select cams only for exact user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In database.phpm define second mysql connection as

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Our primary database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then use

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('select * from users');
```

Hint
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Answer (score 1):

Are they using the same database or are the databases on those apps synced? If not, then this is a bad practice. Well as for passing values from one Laravel app to another, just create endpoints wherein it will send/accept values.

Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers) especially on the [`Controllers`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers) and [`Routing`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing) and  then study on how you will implement it using your own logic.

Comment: No. Databases are different.Nope.They not synced, but users are identical.

Comment: @ИванМазаев it's still a bad practice to use another database to query into another database especially when they're not sync. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but if you really want to communicate with both databases for two separate apps then you should set another connection on your database config.